# Is there any way to find the duplicate values i.e ArrayList from a hash map?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

**For eg:-**

I have declared a hashMap in the form of:

```
Map<String, List<Tracks>> dupItems = new LinkedHashMap();
```

Tracks is a model class that contains name, address, and age.

and I added items in a Tracks

and I added Items as:-

```
dupItems.add("Project",tracks);
dupItems.add("Report",tracks);
```

and what I want is a list of duplicate tracks i.e how can I match the items on the basis of values of tracks i.e all values have to be similar. same name, same address, and same age.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: just iterate the values over the values and equal them, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful can you please a small demo that will be too  much of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are looking for the duplicate map values**, that is, duplicate *lists* of Tracks:

One way you can do this is iterate over the values, putting them all in a `Set` data structure. If you find that the value was already in the set, then it's a duplicate, and you add it to a separate data structure that keeps a record of the duplicate values:

```
Set<List<Tracks>> findDuplicateValues(Map<String, List<Tracks>> dupItems) {
    Set<List<Tracks>> allValues = new HashSet<>();
    Set<List<Tracks>> duplicateValues = new HashSet<>();
    for (List<Tracks> value : dupItems.values()) {
        if (!allValues.add(value)) {
            // It's a duplicate!
            duplicateValues.add(value);
        }
    }
    return duplicateValues;
}
```

For this to work reliably, the `Tracks` class has to implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Comparing two objects with the same values using the `equals` method should return `true`.

**On the other hand, if you are looking for the duplicate `Tracks` values**, no matter which map value list contains them:

you just need to add a loop to the previous method:

```
Set<List<Tracks>> findDuplicateValues(Map<String, List<Tracks>> dupItems) {
    Set<List<Tracks>> allValues = new HashSet<>();
    Set<List<Tracks>> duplicateValues = new HashSet<>();
    for (List<Tracks> value : dupItems.values()) {
        for (Tracks value : values) {
            if (!allValues.add(value)) {
                // It's a duplicate!
                duplicateValues.add(value);
            }
        }

    }
    return duplicateValues;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The OP want to search for duplicate Tracks, not duplicate lists of Tracks.

Comment: The wording in the question is unclear, I'll wait for the OP to confirm if this is what they are looking for

Comment: On a second thought, it's a trivial change, so I'm adding both to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we search for duplicate Tracks instances.

```
public Set<Tracks> findDuplicates(Map<String, List<Tracks>> dupItems) {
    Set<Tracks> all = new HashSet<>();
    return dupItems.values().stream()
            .flatMap(list -> list.stream())  // build a single list of Tracks
            .filter(t -> !all.add(t))        // add track to all set but only continue if duplicate
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());    // store the remaining tracks in a set (to avoid duplicates in the result
}
```

A Set will check on duplicates only if the `equals()` function is correctly implemented.

My eclipse editor generated :

```
private static class Tracks {
    String name;
    String address;
    int age;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + age;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Tracks other = (Tracks) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at Apache Commons [EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)